# а есть ли размытие в SFML вообще?

Tags: c++, sfml

Рисую фигуры составленные из совокупности примитивов (треугольник, круг, прямоугольник ).
Задача такова , что исходя из разных мониторов я должен увеличивать изображения.
поэтому рисую в текстурки, кручу под угол,  а потом увеличиваю. Так вот при увеличении прямые отрезки из которых составлены примитивы совсем не прикольно рисуются: как в 90-х на досе в бейсике ))) а в 21 - ом веке можно как-нибудь сгладить ??? Как мне setSmoth применить чтобы покраше смотрелось в моем случае, можно ли вообще  ? у меня не получается . Платформа Виндовс.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf; // подключаем пространство имен sf

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({ 600,600 }), "test");
    window.clear();

    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::RenderTexture renderTexture;
    const sf::Texture& texture1 = renderTexture.getTexture();
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    if (!renderTexture.create(300, 500));
    {

    }
    renderTexture.display();
    texture.setSmooth(true);
    renderTexture.setSmooth(true);
    sprite.setTexture(texture1);
    sf::ConvexShape tr;
    tr.setPointCount(3);
    tr.setPoint(0, sf::Vector2f(0, 0));
    tr.setPoint(1, sf::Vector2f(90, 190));
    tr.setPoint(2, sf::Vector2f(180, 210));
    tr.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
    tr.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
    tr.setOutlineThickness(1);
    sprite.move(130, 300);
    sprite.setScale(0.5, 0.5);
    sprite.setRotation(45);
    renderTexture.setSmooth(true);
    renderTexture.draw(tr);
    renderTexture.display();
    window.draw(sprite);
    window.display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так если рисовать в текстуру а потом увеличивать, то естественно, что получается апскейл... При включении размытия получится мыльный апскейл. На кой вообще понадобилось рисование в текстуру?

Comment: @user7860670 потому что на текстуре можно нарисовать много чего, а потом повернуть одним махом . или увеличить или сдвинуть всю композицию . очень подкупает именно так сделать. а как бы вы сделали иначе  ?

Comment: Повернуть нарисованное на текстуре можно только на угол, кратный 90 градусам, увеличить нельзя, а сдвинуть можно только на целое число пикселей. Иначе будет мыло. По-хорошему, все это следует делать, используя матрицы для преобразования координат вершин в шейдере.

Comment: повернуть + сдвинуть, сдвинуть - нормально получается и несложно. другое дело увеличить . получается каша

Comment: @user7860670 а что вы имеете ввиду под матрицами преобразования ??? массив координат под каждое разрешение ??? или же высчитывать при помощи тригонометрии координаты вершин ???

Comment: Ну как это обычно делается - создаются матрицы, задающие поворот, сдвиг и увеличение и проекцию, затем в вершинном шейдере координаты каждой вершины умножаются на эти матрицы.

Comment: @user7860670 а есть ссылочки по этой теории ? )))

Comment: По идее в любом более-менее приличном туториале по directx/opengl эта тема затрагивается. Ну а по теории можно почитать какой-нибудь учебник по линейной алгебре.

Comment: @user7860670 кажется нашёл http://oldshatalov.ghost17.ru/ru/articles/math/transformation_1.html

Answer (score 0):

отвечаю сам : увеличение объекта тупо перемножаются координаты объектов и размеры (в случае окружности , прямоугольника) на коэффициент. перемещение тоже просто. поворот на угол можно просто сделать в виде базы данных координат вершин(у меня углов не много). спасибо @user7860670